# How should I set my database connection up in a Java web service?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I'm making a web service in the form of a small forum for a college project. The web service provides a bunch of methods to access and modify a database, and then a JSP/servlet will use that web service to present the forum to users.

I have all my methods set up but I'm still not certain how to properly set up my database connection. Right now I have a `Connection` object in the web service class file and the connection is made in the class's constructor. I use that connection object all the way through in all my methods so they all rely on that constructor being run. I'm not certain that's correct.

Is there a better way of doing this? An instructor told me an instance of the web service gets created every time someone accesses a page, that sounds like an expensive operation to me.

EDIT: I had a look at connection pooling and everything I've found so far (including this requires additional libraries. I'm limited to stock Java SE/EE without additional libraries so that's out of the question.

Comment: Not out of the question if you wrote your own.  But you don't know how to do that, because your professor hasn't covered Map yet.  Oh, well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *very* bad idea.  You should not have a `Connection` object that's shared.  It can't scale like that, and it's not thread-safe.

A better approach is to use a connection pool.  Get the connection when you need it, use it, and close it in the scope of the same method.

I think your friend is misinformed: a web service should stand alone, separate from any pages.  It's managed by a container.  It might be a singleton or a pooled object, but you don't create one for every page.

Comment: So I should open a new connection to the database for every method? I figured that would take a lot more time/resources.

Comment: No, you let the connection pool open and manage the connections.  The service checks out the connection, uses it, and checks it back in.

Comment: I'm confused, is there a connection pool class or object or something like that? My course hasn't covered anything like that.

Comment: If you're confused, don't worry about all the details that you're bringing up here.  Create a connection every time if that's what you know and see how it works out.  When you run into a problem, figure out what to do about it.  You're a student; get the assignment done and then branch out to other things.

Answer (score 0):

Best to post some code however from the brief explanation a couple of problems come to mind:

1. Your not pooling the connections which won't be very effective under any real load.
2. Creating connections are expensive so if you are executing the constructor quite frequently then you'll be creating a lot of connections.
3. Where are you closing the connection?
4. Make sure you guard against sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

You  shouldn't create the connection in the constructor since you will most likely have lots of problems with inactivity, connection state, io problems, ...

I would rather use a DataSource from the Apache libraries such as the [`BasicDataSource`](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html).

```
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:...");
dataSource.setUser(...);
dataSource.setPassword(...);
```

And then, in each method of your web service, you invoke `dataSource.getConnection()` to get a connection. Internally, it uses a connection pool, as suggested in another answer.